# JasperStarter - use MongoDB - JRRuntimeException

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperstarter

```
/home/x/jasperstarter/bin/jasperstarter cp -i test.jrxml
....
    at de.cenote.jasperstarter.App.main(App.java:103)
        Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No query executer factory registered for the 'MongoDbQuery' language.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRQueryExecuterUtils.getExecuterFactory(JRQueryExecuterUtils.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.queryLanguageChanged(JRDesignDataset.java:1163)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRDesignDataset.setQuery(JRDesignDataset.java:630)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign.setQuery(JasperDesign.java:791)
    ... 30 more

    input file: "test.jrxml" is not a valid jrxml file
```

Trying to compile a `.jrxml` file into `.jasper` report with JasperStarter on command line.

Throws Exception not beeing able to find the MongoDB driver.

the `.jrxml` file IS valid, as I can compile it using iReports.

I need a command line working tool to compile - what do I need to do to get further with this...

Comment: It is better to send this question to the authors of this project

Comment: why remove jasperserver tag?

Comment: How this question (about compiling reports with help of [*JasperStarter*](http://jasperstarter.sourceforge.net/) tool) is related with *JasperReports Server*???

Comment: JasperReports Server is where I want the reports to be in, it's the software that wants me to compile the reports

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On installing the JasperServer Commnunity Version (5.1.0),

there will be 2 folders with jars libs:

```
/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib

/opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/buildomatic/conf_source/ieCe/lib
```

One of these HAS the datasource jars, the other DOES NOT.

Try both, one will succeed.